# Adding a total to the end of each row

Tags: sql, count

I have a table containing 15 rows and one of the columns contains either Yes or No.

What I am trying to do is add a total column on the end of my Select * query which will put the number of Yes results on each row containing a Yes and the number of No results on each row containing a No.

There are 8 rows with a Yes and 7 with a now. So, I would expect that each row which contains a Yes in that particular field would have the number 8 in the final column, and 7 for each No.

I'm not sure I've explained that particularly well, but here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT *,
COUNT(Approved) OVER ()  as 'Count_Approved'
FROM 
Approvals
```

That gives me a total of 15 in each line, so I'm missing something pretty basic here.

Sorry about the formatting too, I'm not sure how to make it look all nice.

Cheers

CJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try counting with a partition on the `Approved` column:

```
SELECT *,
    COUNT(Approved) OVER (PARTITION BY Approved) AS Count_Approved
FROM 
    Approvals
ORDER BY
    Site_Code;
```

You never told us what database you are using, but the above is ANSI SQL and should work on most databases.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Yes, it's SQL 2008. 
That query works a treat, but the only issue now is that it is now ordered by the Count_Approved results - so I have the 7 No rows then the 8 Yes rows. I need them to remain in their original order.

Comment: @CJD What column(s) defines the original order?

Comment: Site_Code
I know I can just do an Order By, but is there a way to do it without that?

Comment: @CJD No, the only way to guarantee the order of a result set is via `ORDER BY`.  So this is likely what you will have to use.

Comment: Great, thanks very much.  I thought that was probably the case, but I was curious as I was told there was a way to do it.  Order By seems like the easiest and fastest way to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are looking for but my guess is

```
select Approved, count(Approved) over (PARTITION BY Approved) [Count] from  Approvals
```

Result :

```
Approved    Count
Now         2
Now         2
Yes         3
Yes         3
Yes         3
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Yogesh Sharma.